# Result based on column value aggregated by month/year & a threshold

Tags: sql, database, join

I have the following table

Fact table `f`:

| date | partner | stake |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022/01/01 | AA | 10 |
| 2022/01/01 | BB | 22 |
| 2022/01/01 | DD | 22 |
| 2022/01/02 | AA | 5 |
| 2022/01/02 | BB | 9 |
| 2022/01/10 | AA | 10 |
| 2022/01/31 | AA | 20 |
| 2022/01/31 | BB | 2 |
| 2022/02/01 | AA | 10 |

and an external table like this:

Manual_file `mf`:

| date | partner | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022/01/01 | AA | 10% |
| 2022/01/01 | BB | 10% |
| 2022/01/02 | AA | 10% |
| 2022/01/02 | BB | 10% |
| 2022/01/03 | AA | 10% |
| 2022/01/04 | AA | 10% |
| 2022/01/05 | AA | 10% |
| 2022/01/06 | AA | 10% |
| 2022/01/07 | AA | 10% |
| 2022/01/08 | AA | 10% |
| 2022/01/09 | AA | 10% |
| 2022/01/08 | AA | 10% |
| 2022/01/10 | AA | 10% |
| 2022/01/11 | AA | 10% |
| 2022/01/12 | AA | 10% |
| 2022/01/13 | AA | 10% |
| 2022/01/31 | AA | 10% |
| 2022/01/31 | BB | 10% |
| 2022/02/01 | AA | 10% |

I'm performing a left join between the fact and the external tables using (date, partner). Based on this join, I'm multiplying the column `f.stake` by the percentage from the column `mf.value`. So far it's pretty simple :

```
    SELECT 
        f.date, 
        f.partner,
        f.spent,
        CASE
            WHEN MAX(mf.value) = "10%" 
                         THEN COALESCE(SUM(f.Stake) * 0.10, 0)
        END AS budget
    FROM
        fact f
    LEFT JOIN 
        manual_file mf USING (date, partner)
```

I get the following result:

| date | partner | stake | budget |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022/01/01 | AA | 10 | 1 |
| 2022/01/01 | BB | 22 | 2,2 |
| 2022/01/01 | DD | 22 | 0 |
| 2022/01/02 | AA | 5 | 0,5 |
| 2022/01/02 | BB | 9 | 0,9 |
| 2022/01/10 | AA | 10 | 1 |
| 2022/01/31 | AA | 20 | 2 |
| 2022/01/31 | BB | 2 | 0,2 |
| 2022/01/31 | AA | 10 | 1 |

Imagine the same query, but with an another rule saying that if the sum of the previous rows (for the same month and for partners AA & BB), is equal or higher than 5, then nothing is happening (budget is 0).
I haven't been able to give the expected result just below. I tried some stuff with window function, to group by month/year, but I'm stuck with the fact that I have multiple partners to take care of..

Expected result :

| date | partner | stake | budget | explaination of budget column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022/01/01 | AA | 10 | 1 | sum of previous AA&BB<5=> 10*0,1 |
| 2022/01/01 | BB | 22 | 2,2 | sum of previous AA&BB<5=> 22*0,1 |
| 2022/01/01 | DD | 22 | 0 | no match with mf |
| 2022/01/02 | AA | 5 | 0,5 | sum of previous AA&BB<5=> 5*0,1 |
| 2022/01/02 | BB | 9 | 0,9 | sum of previous AA&BB<5=> 9*0,1 |
| 2022/01/10 | AA | 10 | 0,4 | sum of previous AA&BB<5 but if I multiply the stake value (10) by 0,1, total will be higher than 5!(1+2,2+0,5+0,9+1 = 5,6) so budget value is 0,4. |
| 2022/01/31 | AA | 20 | 0 | sum of previous AA&BB=5 => 0 |
| 2022/01/31 | BB | 2 | 0 | sum of previous AA&BB=5 => 0 |
| 2022/02/01 | AA | 10 | 1 | sum of previous AA&BB on february is 0 (<5) so =>10*0.1 |

Any help would be appreciated to solve this problem,

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but I haven't really understood the calculation of what you want but here I can show you how to have the sum of rows up to and including the current row. Please adjust to meet your needs.

> ```
> create table facture (
>   fdate date,
>   partner char(2),
>   stake int,
>   spent int);
> insert into facture values
>
> ('2022/01/01','AA', 10 , 0   ),
> ('2022/01/01','BB', 22 , 0   ),
> ('2022/01/01','DD', 22 , 0   ),
> ('2022/01/02','AA', 5  , 5   ),
> ('2022/01/02','BB', 9  , 0   ),
> ('2022/01/02','FF', 9  , 10  ),
> ('2022/01/10','AA', 10 , 0   ),
> ('2022/01/22','BB', 20 , 0   ),
> ('2022/01/31','AA', 20 , 0   ),
> ('2022/01/31','BB', 2  , 0   );
>
> create table manual (
>   mdate date,
>   partner char(2),
>   value int);
> inset into manual values
> ('2022/01/01','AA', 10 ),
> ('2022/01/01','BB', 10 ),
> ('2022/01/02','AA', 10 ),
> ('2022/01/02','BB', 10 ),
> ('2022/01/10','AA', 10 ),
> ('2022/01/22','BB', 10 ),
> ('2022/01/31','AA', 10 ),
> ('2022/01/31','BB', 10 );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> with frank as
> (select f.partner , f.fdate, 
> sum(f.stake) sumStake,
> sum(f.spent) sumSpent,
> rank() over (partition by f.partner
>              order by f.fdate) ranking
> from facture f 
> group by f.partner, f.fdate)
>
> select 
>   f.partner,
>   f.fdate,
>   f.ranking,
>   f.sumStake,
>   (select sum(sumStake)from frank k where k.ranking<=f.ranking and k.partner=f.partner) cumulStake,
>   f.sumSpent,
>   (select sum(sumSpent)from frank k where k.ranking<=f.ranking and k.partner=f.partner) cumulSpent,
>   (select sum(sumStake) - sum(sumSpent)from frank k where k.ranking<=f.ranking and k.partner=f.partner) budgetLeft
> from frank f
> left join manual m 
> on f.fdate=m.mdate
> and f.partner=m.partner
> order by fdate, f.partner;
>
> /*SELECT (SELECT SUM(asum) FROM cteRanked c2 WHERE c2.rownum <= c1.rownum),*/
> ```
>
> ```
> partner | fdate      | ranking | sumStake | cumulStake | sumSpent | cumulSpent | budgetLeft
> :------ | :--------- | ------: | -------: | ---------: | -------: | ---------: | ---------:
> AA      | 2022-01-01 |       1 |       10 |         10 |        0 |          0 |         10
> BB      | 2022-01-01 |       1 |       22 |         22 |        0 |          0 |         22
> DD      | 2022-01-01 |       1 |       22 |         22 |        0 |          0 |         22
> AA      | 2022-01-02 |       2 |        5 |         15 |        5 |          5 |         10
> BB      | 2022-01-02 |       2 |        9 |         31 |        0 |          0 |         31
> FF      | 2022-01-02 |       1 |        9 |          9 |       10 |         10 |         -1
> AA      | 2022-01-10 |       3 |       10 |         25 |        0 |          5 |         20
> BB      | 2022-01-22 |       3 |       20 |         51 |        0 |          0 |         51
> AA      | 2022-01-31 |       4 |       20 |         45 |        0 |          5 |         40
> BB      | 2022-01-31 |       4 |        2 |         53 |        0 |          0 |         53
>
> ✓
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=a292f015e39eee355be3fb90a4ac6507)*

Comment: Hi @Kendle, thanks for reply and sorry for my question which was unclear. I edited it. I hope it's more clear for you now.

The solution you gave is almost good, but the tricky part is that the partners AA and BB should be considered as the same entity.

Let me know if you need more explanations to understand it